# value parse is not a member of object org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: scala, jenkins, gradle, jodatime, joda-convert

While Building My code in jenkins , I am getting  following error,

```
value parse is not a member of object org.joda.time.DateTime [ant:scalac]
var broadcastDate = DateTime.parse(attributesMap("processingDate"), 
DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat)).plusDays(i)
```

### While I am able to build in my local, but not in jenkins.

Also I added joda-convert dependecies in my `build.gradle`
Still I am getting same error.

Comment: How do you build on you local machine? Via gradle or Intellij?

Comment: Using Intellij @Peter

Comment: Try to delegate all builds to gradle and I guess that your build will fail locally as well. See https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2016/11/gradle-goodness-delegate-build-and-run.html

Comment: In local I got stackoverflow error, that i resolved, but dont know how to resolve this error.

Comment: Check which gradle version you use locally and on your build machine. 
Make sure to use the same version. Are you using a `GradleWrapper`?